# Gate times for different qubit technologies

Tags: quantum-gate

Different qubit technologies exist and for each, operations are implemented differently. My question is what the typical times are for the standard gates (single qubit rotations, Hadamard, CNOT, T, Toffoli, etc.) for the most common qubit technologies?

Furthermore, as quantum technology advances, improvements are expected in qubit coherence times among other things. Is there a limit and if so, what is it, on the gate times of above?

Comment: I found something about relaxation and dephasing time on IBM Q: https://www.ibm.com/blogs/research/2019/03/power-quantum-device/